# Как получить значение текстового поля на js?

Tags: javascript

```js
var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("N").value);
var m = parseInt(document.getElementById("M").value);
var ch = document.getElementById("CH");
var chisla = new Object();
chisla["add"] = document.getElementById("ch");
summa = n + m;

function PrintSolve() {
  document.getElementById("solve").value = summa;
}
```

```html
<p>Введите число N - сумма чисел в нечетных разрядах</p>
<input type="text" id="N" size="10" maxlength="15" value="" />
<p>Введите число M - количество знаков в числе:</p>
<input type="text" id="M" size="10" maxlength="15" value="" />
<p>Введите число K- количество чисел:</p>
<input type="text" id="K" size="10" maxlength="15" value="" />
<p>Введите числа:</p>
<input type="text" id="CH" size="10" maxlength="15" value="" />
<p onclick="PrintSolve()">Решение</p>
<p><textarea id="solve" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea></p>
```

Comment: все) не сразу увидела

Comment: И еще... чтобы объект `chisla` получал бы какое-то значение из `input-ОВ` должно происходить какое то событие...

Comment: да, я знаю. я пока для начала хочу понять, как получать данные из текстового поля и обрабатывать их, как числа

Comment: Почему выводит NaN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что при событии `on-click` У тебя значение пустые

На момент когда срабатывает функция должно определяться  значение

```js
var n = document.getElementById("N");
var m = document.getElementById("M");

function PrintSolve() {
  summa = parseInt(n.value) + parseInt(m.value);
  document.getElementById("solve").value = summa;
}
```

```html
<p>Введите число N - сумма чисел в нечетных разрядах</p>
<input type="text" id="N" size="10" maxlength="15" value="" />
<p>Введите число M - количество знаков в числе:</p>
<input type="text" id="M" size="10" maxlength="15" value="" />

<p onclick="PrintSolve()">Решение</p>
<p><textarea id="solve" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea></p>
```

Comment: аа, поняла. а как тогда сделать, чтобы из текстового поля бралось значение и присваивалось переменной?

Comment: изначально поля пустые